# Find a number with Oracle regexp that has an exact length of 3

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to get only 456.

I tried this regular expression, but I got all numbers which contain 3 digit characters, 456, 46354376, etc.

```
select regexp_substr(MY_COLUMN,'([[:digit:]]{3})') from MY_TABLE
```

Answer (score 7):

I'm not quite clear on whether you want exact matches or sub-string matches so I've included various options:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b970/22)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (MY_COLUMN) AS
          SELECT '456' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT '12345678' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'abc 123 def 456' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If you only want rows where `MY_COLUMN` contains exactly a 3-digit number then you can just use your regular expression wrapped in the start-string (`^`) and end-string (`$`) anchors:

```
    SELECT MY_COLUMN
    FROM   MY_TABLE
    WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( MY_COLUMN, '^[[:digit:]]{3}$' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b970/22/0)**:

```
| MY_COLUMN |
|-----------|
|       456 |
```

**Query 2**:

Or, if you are using Oracle 11g then you can use the less verbose PERL syntax:

```
    SELECT MY_COLUMN
    FROM   MY_TABLE
    WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( MY_COLUMN, '^\d{3}$' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b970/22/1)**:

```
| MY_COLUMN |
|-----------|
|       456 |
```

**Query 3**:

If you want to extract the first 3-digit number from the column (where it can have surrounding text or more digits), then:

```
    SELECT MY_COLUMN,
           REGEXP_INSTR( MY_COLUMN, '\d{3}' ), 
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( MY_COLUMN, '\d{3}' )
    FROM   MY_TABLE
    WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( MY_COLUMN, '\d{3}' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b970/22/2)**:

```
|       MY_COLUMN | REGEXP_INSTR(MY_COLUMN,'\D{3}') | REGEXP_SUBSTR(MY_COLUMN,'\D{3}') |
|-----------------|---------------------------------|----------------------------------|
|             456 |                               1 |                              456 |
|        12345678 |                               1 |                              123 |
| abc 123 def 456 |                               5 |                              123 |
```

**Query 4**:

If you want to extract the first exactly 3-digit number from the column then:

```
    SELECT MY_COLUMN,
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR( MY_COLUMN, '(^|\D)\d{3}(\D|$)' ), '\d{3}' ) AS match
    FROM   MY_TABLE
    WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( MY_COLUMN, '(^|\D)\d{3}(\D|$)' )
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b970/22/3)**:

```
|       MY_COLUMN | MATCH |
|-----------------|-------|
|             456 |   456 |
| abc 123 def 456 |   123 |
```

**Query 5**:

If you want to extract all the non-overlapping 3-digit numbers from the column (where it can have surrounding text), then:

```
    WITH re_counts AS (
      SELECT MY_COLUMN,
             REGEXP_COUNT( MY_COLUMN, '\d{3}' ) AS re_count
      FROM   MY_TABLE
    )
    ,indexes AS (
      SELECT LEVEL AS "index"
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX( re_count)  FROM re_counts)
    )
    SELECT MY_COLUMN,
           "index", 
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( MY_COLUMN, '\d{3}', 1, "index" )
    FROM   re_counts
           INNER JOIN
           indexes
           ON ("index" <= re_count)
    ORDER BY MY_COLUMN, "index"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b970/22/4)**:

```
|       MY_COLUMN | INDEX | REGEXP_SUBSTR(MY_COLUMN,'\D{3}',1,"INDEX") |
|-----------------|-------|--------------------------------------------|
|        12345678 |     1 |                                        123 |
|        12345678 |     2 |                                        456 |
|             456 |     1 |                                        456 |
| abc 123 def 456 |     1 |                                        123 |
| abc 123 def 456 |     2 |                                        456 |
```

**Query 6**:

If you want to extract all the sub-matches which are exactly 3-digit numbers then:

```
    WITH re_counts AS (
      SELECT MY_COLUMN,
             REGEXP_COUNT( MY_COLUMN, '(^|\D)\d{3}(\D|$)' ) AS re_count
      FROM   MY_TABLE
    )
    ,indexes AS (
      SELECT LEVEL AS "index"
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX( re_count)  FROM re_counts)
    )
    SELECT MY_COLUMN,
           "index", 
           REGEXP_SUBSTR( REGEXP_SUBSTR( MY_COLUMN, '(^|\D)\d{3}(\D|$)', 1, "index" ), '\d{3}' ) AS match
    FROM   re_counts
           INNER JOIN
           indexes
           ON ("index" <= re_count)
    ORDER BY MY_COLUMN, "index"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b970/22/5)**:

```
|       MY_COLUMN | INDEX | MATCH |
|-----------------|-------|-------|
|             456 |     1 |   456 |
| abc 123 def 456 |     1 |   123 |
| abc 123 def 456 |     2 |   456 |
```

**Query 7**:

If you want to extract all 3-digit numbers from a column regardless of whether those matches partially overlap or not then:

```
    WITH positions AS (
      SELECT LEVEL AS pos
      FROM   DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (SELECT MAX( LENGTH( MY_COLUMN ) - 2 )  FROM MY_TABLE )
    )
    SELECT MY_COLUMN,
           pos, 
           SUBSTR( MY_COLUMN, pos, 3 )
    FROM   MY_TABLE
           INNER JOIN
           positions
           ON (pos <= LENGTH( MY_COLUMN ) - 2 )
    WHERE  REGEXP_LIKE( SUBSTR( MY_COLUMN, pos, 3 ), '^\d{3}$' )
    ORDER BY MY_COLUMN, pos
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6b970/22/6)**:

```
|       MY_COLUMN | POS | SUBSTR(MY_COLUMN,POS,3) |
|-----------------|-----|-------------------------|
|        12345678 |   1 |                     123 |
|        12345678 |   2 |                     234 |
|        12345678 |   3 |                     345 |
|        12345678 |   4 |                     456 |
|        12345678 |   5 |                     567 |
|        12345678 |   6 |                     678 |
|             456 |   1 |                     456 |
| abc 123 def 456 |   5 |                     123 |
| abc 123 def 456 |  13 |                     456 |
```

Comment: Good one. I have another doubt. How do I get all the digits out of a string. I am trying ----select REGEXP_SUBSTR('somestring-051-a92', '[0-9]+..[0-9]+', 1) ---- This gives me 051-a92.... How do I get 05192 out?

Comment: @androboy Replace all the non-digit characters - `REGEXP_REPLACE('somestring-051-a92','\D')` or, equivalently using POSIX style, `REGEXP_REPLACE('somestring-051-a92','[^[:digit:]]')`

Comment: Yeah, but the trouble is redshift is not having regexp replace currently. so I was thinking of doing regexp substr 20 times and append as my string is fixed length 20 characters

Answer (score 1):

You're sub-stringing the number... if you're searching for a number that is exactly 3 digits then use [`LENGTH()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions088.htm#SQLRF51480):

```
 select * from my_table where length(my_column) = 3
```

This presupposes that you've stored your numbers in a NUMBER column. If there might be characters in there as well use [`REGEXP_LIKE()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52149) and ensure you tie the regular expression to the beginning (with the `^` operator) and end (`$`) of the string

```
select * from my_table where regexp_like( my_column, '^[[:digit:]]{3}$')
```

You're not checking to see whether your number is at both the beginning and end of the string so you're getting everything with 3 numbers.

Comment: my db table contains non numeric characters for ex: </br> row1->> im column456test    </b> row2->> column4567839asdf </b>row3->> ddffgg987qwert   from these rows i want to get from first row 456 and from third row 987 thank to reply

Comment: So REGEXP_LIKE() then... it's just a little slower that's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
(^|[^[:digit:]])([[:digit:]]{3})($|[^[:digit:]])
```

where `[^[:digit:]]` is *all that is not a digit* and `^`, `$` are start and end of the string anchors.

Comment: 456 not exact, but also i want to get number that's length equal to 3. in my question i got at least has 3 length of number. but i want to find equal to 3 length that numbre has.

Comment: @robert: Yes, I see, refresh your page.

Comment: it worked correcly but my numbers left ant right side has double quote your pattern gets "456" ,is there any way to get only 456. thanks @casimire et Hippolyte

Comment: @robertlennon: replace all non-digit characters by an empty string.